# D3 - ternary operator to set class name

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/qDi8bm3xh3hdaV059AXX?p=preview

I have a chart with two sets of bars.

The bars are coloured using a ternary operator and colours from an array.

I'd like to set an opacity and fill pattern on the bars so need to add classes to the bars.

How can I use the ternary operator to add classes to the bars.

```
.style('fill', (d, i) => {
    return i % 2 ? colors[1] : colors[0]
})
```

Comment: The ternary operator doesn't care whether you use it to choose a class or a style. It works always the same way.

Comment: why don't you use `(d, i) => colors[i%2]`

Comment: You might know that you don't need the return keyword when you have a one line argument , `.attr('class', (d, i) => i % 2 ? 'bar-fill' : 'bar-opacity')`

Answer (score -1):

```
.attr('class', (d, i) => {
    return i % 2 ? 'bar-fill' : 'bar-opacity'
})
```